# Knockout two-way binding getting lost

Tags: binding, knockout.js

I have an observable collection that is populated from a service. The UI is constructred using containerless `ko` tags. I have input boxes which are being bound correctly, but two-way binding is not updating the VM.

I have a reproduced my problem in http://jsfiddle.net/cooper/EHNct/18/

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in your value binding of your inputs. By using the function call `volume()` you explicitely unwrap the value contained in your observable so that wat is put in your input become static.

Use the simple `volume` definition in your data binding and everything will works fine.

Comment: Thanks Gizmo, spot on!! I love Knockout! I hate Knockout! I love Knockout! I hate Knockout! ;-)